# Running startup.auth again in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-authentication

I can change the googleauth values on the website and toggle the ability to use it on or off. Right now i need to restart the project to apply the changes, and my question is: Can i run startup.auth so the settings apply without having to restart the project?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it, but if its only the value you want to change, you can set those values in the web.config appSettings

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="googleauthwhatever" value="myValue" />
```

And get it

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleauthwhatever"]
```